# Does a 240 volt single phase air compressor need a starter

Tags: electrical

Compressor model aside its a 2 stage with a check valve at the tank so start up amps are motor only. I ask because it is equipped with a DPDT *pressure switch* that is caring both legs of the 240. Then power goes to a starter from the PS for some reason. The coil is wired to one leg and the holding contact is wired, and the more I think about it the more redundant it seems.
IMO there's no need for the starter,- other than the *over load*- if you aren't using the coil to hold the contacts. Also there is no ON/OFF switch. I would like to replace the PS contacts or the hole switch, its due, and that is what started this inquiry.  Scratching head.
Thanks.

Comment: "due"? Is there visible damage?

Answer (score 1):

The starter is a very good idea.  It precludes an accidental restart in the event the power is interrupted and then reestablished up stream. With this kind of a load you want redundancy; for safety sake.  That overload is very important on this type of high torque load.  It helps to protect your motor; the most expensive replacement part.

Answer (score 1):

All motors that do not have internal thermal safetys or overloads should have starters. Starters do 2 things they provide overload protection that allows the motor to start high in rush currents of 3-7 times normal running power wile protecting the wiring and motor if the motor dosent properly start a class 10 starter will fault in 10 seconds saving the motor then the supply wiring. The second thing most starters usually do is use a relay or contactor to turn the power on, contactor are orders of magnitude faster than hand operated switches and less arcing at start up and power down. So should the motor have a starter? If it has internal protection it is not needed but if it doesent it should have a starter for protection.